# Select2 Multi-select boxes keep dropdown opened when cmd button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `jquery select2` multi-select boxes (https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox).

When I select an option from the dropdown menu, the menu is suddenly close. I noticed that in Win /Linux system , if I keep pressed the CTRL button when I select the option , the dropdown menu remains open. 
I did expect the same behavior in MAC OS if I press the cmd button, but it doesn't.

Is it possible to force the opening of the dropdown menu in the select2 if the cmd button is pressed during the selection?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I report here the solution for anyone can have the same issue:

On the select2 documentation I noticed that there is an option to programmatically open the dropdown menu `$('#my_select').select2('open')` .

So I listened to the select event and I triggered the command above if `cmd` key was pressed

```
$('#my_select2').on('select2:select', function(ev) {if (ev.params.originalEvent.metaKey) { $(ev.target).select2('open'); } })
```